# A super smart rebus

Tags: word, wordplay, lateral-thinking, rebus

This rebus describes exactly just how smart I am.

[image: super smart rebus]

Comment: "I am floored wain swimming dog." Nailed it.

Comment: You certainly nailed something ... but not this puzzle :P

Comment: @feelinferrety, no. cryptic-clues is for "cryptic clues of the type found in cryptic crosswords"

Comment: Don't insult yourself, please.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are an

> imbecile

breakdown:

> I'm + (bust - t) + [seal](http://www.buzzfeed.com/ryroify/seals-are-the-dogs-of-the-sea-24ty)

Comment: So very close. It might help your quest for the last bit if I told you the answer was actually a noun.

Comment: @Matt Yeah, I couldn't tell which form it was supposed to be.